# why is this extra check necessary in if condition?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var any = _.some = _.any = function(obj, predicate, context) {
    predicate || (predicate = _.identity);
    var result = false;
    if (obj == null) return result;
    if (nativeSome && obj.some === nativeSome) return obj.some(predicate, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (result || (result = predicate.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
    });
    return !!result;
  };
```

above is the implementation of _.any method in underscore.js.
when testing for predicate method's result in following line,

```
if (result || (result = predicate.call(context, value, index, list)))
```

the `result` is `false` from the start, and the loop terminates when `result` variable is set to true by calling `predicate` function. so it seems to me that the first check for `result` variable will always evaluate to `false`. why is there an extra test for this variable?

Comment: result can be set at any time inside the each() callback. if result is not falsy, the each() function terminates early, just like the real [].some() that underscore rips off and slows down...

Comment: @dandavis result can only be set by predicate.call(), no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an issue about this on github by ***lshearer***

> When a native forEach function is present, if _.any is called with a
>   list in which the last item does not pass the truth test it will
>   always return false (even if any other items in the list passed the
>   truth test). The problem is that the native forEach function does not
>   short circuit (return breaker; has no effect on it). Therefore, the
>   return result for the call to _.any will be overwritten by the last
>   item.

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/177

If you look at the implementation of `each` it uses the native forEach if it is available.

```
// The cornerstone, an `each` implementation, aka `forEach`.
// Handles objects with the built-in `forEach`, arrays, and raw objects.
// Delegates to **ECMAScript 5**'s native `forEach` if available.
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  if (obj == null) return obj;
  if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
    obj.forEach(iterator, context);
  } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
    for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  } else {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (iterator.call(context, obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj) === breaker) return;
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

So apparently the extra check is necessary.